# How can I update GNOME Shell extensions from the command line?

Tags: command-line, updates, gnome-shell-extension

Occassionally I get messages telling me there is an update for one of my GNOME Shell extensions, directing me to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ where I can trigger an update through the web interface.

I would rather invoke updates from the command line, similar to calling `apt update && apt upgrade`. How can I do this?

Comment: You could utilise a `cron` job to extract shell extensions from the `/etc/shells` file, and run `apt-get` updates for each value - just one idea.

Comment: @ThePizzaOverlord These tend not to be packaged things and when they are, they're often superseded by the versions provided by Gnome directly.

Comment: See [gnome-shell issue #906](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/906) for a request to add this feature.

Answer (score 16):

The comments on [this omgubuntu.co.uk article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-update-gnome-extensions) list two possible ways:

1. The [GNOME Shell Extension Installer · Github](https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer), a *bash script to install and search extensions from extensions.gnome.org*.
   Install it with

   ```bsh
   wget -O gnome-shell-extension-installer "https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer/raw/master/gnome-shell-extension-installer"
   chmod +x gnome-shell-extension-installer
   sudo mv gnome-shell-extension-installer /usr/bin/
   ```

Update the extensions `23` and `42` for GNOME Shell `3.18.4` with

```bsh
    ids=( 23 42 )
    gnome=3.18.4
    gnome-shell-extension-installer ${ids[@]} $gnome --yes --update --restart-shell
```

Update all extensions with

```bsh
    gnome-shell-extension-installer --yes --update --restart-shell
```

I couldn’t test it, but I’m pretty sure it’s scriptable.

1. If you installed your extensions by cloning their git repos to `/path/` you can just **`git pull`** the repos one after one:

   ```bsh
   for i in /path/*; do
     git -C "$i" pull
   done
   ```

After that you need to reload GNOME Shell with either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `r` or the command `gnome-shell -r`.

Answer (score 0):

The [gnomeshell-extension-manage](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/blob/master/ubuntugnome/gnomeshell-extension-manage) script by Nicolas Bernaerts allows to install and remove GNOME Shell extensions both system-wide and in user space.

Here's how you would install it:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/ubuntugnome/gnomeshell-extension-manage
chmod 755 gnomeshell-extension-manage
sudo mv -iv gnomeshell-extension-manage /usr/local/bin/gnome-shell-extension-manage
```

This makes it available for every user: (alongside similar GNOME commands)

```
$ gnome-shell-extension-manage 
Install/remove extension from Gnome Shell Extensions site https://extensions.gnome.org/
Extension ID should be retrieved from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/<ID>/extension-name/
Version installed will be targeted as the same as Gnome Shell or the next available one
Parameters are :
  --install               Install extension (default)
  --remove                Remove extension
  --user                  Installation/remove in user mode (default)
  --system                Installation/remove in system mode
  --version <version>     Force Gnome version (use 'latest' to force latest one)
  --extension-id <id>     Extension ID in Gnome Shell Extension site (compulsory)
```

The [Gnome Shell - Management of Extensions from console](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/345-gnome-shell-install-remove-extension-command-line-script) blog post explains in detail how it is used. For updating an extension you need to add `--version latest` to the command.

---

The two main differences, technically speaking, to Ian Brunelli's [gnome-shell-extension-installer](https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer) are that you can do system-wide installations and that it's using `wget` instead of `curl` to download the extensions.

Comment: If you run `gnome-shell-extension-install` as `sudo`, it will install system-wide.